# How to print $ in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I want output as $msg1 two three. No space between $ and msg1. How it possible?

```
#!/bin/sh
msg1=$
ms="$msg1 msg1"
msg2="$ms two"
msg3="$msg2 three"
echo $msg3
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use:

```
msg1='$'
ms="${msg1}msg1"
msg2="$ms two"
msg3="$msg2 three"
echo "$msg3"
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
$msg1 two three
```

PS: Take note of `${msg1}` syntax to create variable boundary around `msg1`. This is used to avoid it making it `$msg1msg1`

Answer (score 9):

Just quote the `$` (or also the word around it). E.g.

```
 echo '$'

 echo 'some$inside'
```

If you want a message without newline, use `echo -n`

See [echo(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/echo.1.html) and [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple:

Input:

```
echo '$msg1' two three
```

(note the single quotes)

Output:

```
$msg1 two three
```