# I want to print $ in shell, but it is always deleted

Tags: shell

In a Linux shell, I want to print:

```
$300    
$400
```

But when I do `echo -e "$300\n$400"` it shows:

```
00      
00
```

When I do `printf "$300\n$400"` it shows the same thing!

So why does shell delete my dollar sign and the number right after it? Is there a way to print what I want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25036555/how-to-print-in-shell-script

Comment: @GeralexGR Not the same problem though

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape dollar `$`, since you are using double quotes, This will ensure the word is not interpreted by the shell.

```
$ echo -e "\$300\n\$400" 
$300
$400
```

You may be aware how to access variables,

Example :

```
$ test="foo"
$ echo "$test"
foo
```

Suppose if you want to print `$test`, then you have use either

```
$ echo "\$test"
$test
```

OR with single quotes

```
$ echo '$test'
$test
```

Answer (score 1):

In the shell, the `$` character has a special meaning. It means "replace the $ and the following word or digit or special character with the value of a variable of that name". For example:

```
currency='EUR'
echo "The currency is $currency"
```

The variables 0, 1, 2, etc. contain the command line arguments to the program. So if you run your program as `my-program Hello, world`, you can write this code:

```
echo "argument 1 is $1"
echo "argument 2 is $2"
echo "both together are $1 $2, and all arguments are $*"
```

To make the $ character lose this special meaning, it must be written as `\$`. For example:

```
price=123
echo "The price is $price\$"
```

The first $ refers to the variable, and the second $ is escaped.

Alternatively you can surround your string in `'single quotes'`, which removes the special meaning of *all* characters.

To learn more about this topic, run the `man bash` command and read the section about variable expansion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quote. Enclosing characters in single-quotes (') shall preserve the literal value of each character within the single-quotes, where as enclosing characters in double-quotes(") shall preserve the literal value of all characters within the double-quotes, with the exception of the characters back quote, dollar-sign, and backslash.

```
echo -e '$'300"\n"'$'400
```

Comment: No it doesn't work. When you do echo '$300\n$400' it shows $300\n$400

Comment: Single quotes escape everything including new line character. If you want to print new line, try - echo -e '$'300"\n" '$'400. Here you put only dollar sign in single quote and new line in double quote.

Answer (score 0):

`$` has special meaning to the shell; when it sees a `$`, it expects an existing shell variable name to follow. For example, `$PATH`.

In your case, you don't want the shell to think that you're trying to print out the value of shell variables, so you must tell the shell that the `$` is indeed what you want to be displayed. This is done by preceding it with a backslash as explained in other answers.

Adding a backslash before characters is called escaping them (yes, not the most obvious terminology), and you are already using some escape characters unknowingly. (`\n`)

This applies to display other operators too, such as `=`, `:`, etc. Hope that helps.